# Брейкпоинт рулит

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Добрый день!

Общий случай: при выполнении программы некорректно работает функция... если же поставить в ней брейкпоинт, то все отработает корректно.

Какие могут быть причины?

Comment: приложение многопоточное? есть чтение-запись с/из сети?

Comment: Возможно необнуление переменной. В дебаге память заполнена нулями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл поставить Refresh/Repaint и при нормальной работе перерисовка не вызывается, а при брейке IDE временно накрывает окно, обеспечивая таким образом его перерисовку.

Побольше конкретики. О чём функция? Какой оператор не работает?

Comment: К предыдущим постам: в дебаге память необязательно заполнена нулями.
Ещё может быть ошибка, если программа не дожидается завершения процесса/потока, а при брейке процесс/поток успевает доработать и кажется, что всё нормально.